# HttpSessionStateBase Session in ASP.NET MVC is null when accessing site from an iframe

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, iframe, content-security-policy, .net-4.8

I am setting a few variables up when the page loads. Example: `UserId`.

I then access this data later by using `Session["UserId"]` and this works when I load the page by itself. However, when I put the site into an Iframe embedded on another page, the request to get my variable throws an error

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

My first thought was CSP (Content-Security-Policy) "frame-src" didn't include the domain of the parent website. I added it, but no luck.

Why aren't I getting the Session variables I setup on load on subsequent requests?

Using ASP.NET MVC on .NET 4.8.